# ionic not load image from url wp-json and ionic4

Tags: wordpress, image, api, http-status-code-403, ionic4

when I connect ionic app with wordpress blog with wp-json all content loaded without image , I use ion-img
thanks

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIUXB.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0B6x.png)

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZgpG.png)

[screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ5NU.png)

[screenshot5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94keH.png)

this is my code : 
  note : I use all in one security plugin on my wordpress blog

```
  //post.service.ts

  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
  import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

  import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
  import get from "lodash/get";

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class PostsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    private baseURL = "domain.com";
    fetchPosts() {
      return this.http
        .get(`${this.baseURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed`)
        .pipe(
          map((posts: Array<any>) => posts.map(this.setEmbeddedFeaturedImage))
        );
    }

    fetchPost(post_id: string) {
      return this.http
        .get(`${this.baseURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/${post_id}?_embed`)
        .pipe(map((post: any) => this.setEmbeddedFeaturedImage(post)));
    }

    /**
     * Makes the featured image parameter easily accessible in a template
     */
    private setEmbeddedFeaturedImage(p) {
      return Object.assign({}, p, {
        featured_image: get(p, "_embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url")
      });
    }

    fetchPostCategories() {
      return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/categories`);
    }

    fetchPostsByCategory(category_id: string) {
      return this.http
        .get(
          `${this.baseURL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&categories=${category_id}`
        )
        .pipe(
          map((posts: Array<any>) => posts.map(this.setEmbeddedFeaturedImage))
        );
  }
  }
```

in the post view every thing loaded without the post images but the images url open in the browser 
//home view :

```
   <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>
        title
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
      <ion-card class="welcome-card" (click)="loadPost(post)" padding-bottom *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
        <img src="{{post.featured_image}}" >

        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{post.title.rendered}}</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ion-card-title>{{post.title.rendered}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>

        <ion-card-content>
          <div>
            <div [innerHTML]="post.excerpt.rendered"></div>
          </div>
          <ion-button href="#">مشاهدة المزيد</ion-button>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>

  </ion-content>
```

//

Comment: Could you expand on exactly what your problem is, including a minimal code example to reproduce the error. Also it would be helpful if you included your code as actual code instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved successfully for now, I found the problem from the firewall generated by the "All in one security plugin" of the wordpress , I am currently disabled the plugin 
firewall roles until there is an exception option for the site's API. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now, is possible with this plugin.
[Better Rest API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-rest-api-featured-images/)

After you should used in the file `.html`

```
<ion-img [src]="noticia?.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.medium.source_url">
</ion-img>
```

Regards